# Parsing a numpy list read from binary via fromfile

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, binary

I have a 1D array of integers read in from a binary via

```
data = np.fromfile(file.dat, 'u1')
```

where data returns

```
array([242, 255, 101, 0, 124, 0, 86, 0, 33, 0, 
       112, 0, 32, 1, 74, 1, 195, 0, 16, 0], dtype=uint8)
```

The `0's` in the series represent extra bits used for values over or under the standard 256. For example the `244` at index 0 should be -14 and is represented by 255 (or 256) - 242. Conversely the value at index 13 - reading as 32 is actuality 256 + 32, or 288. I'm trying to get the above array to look like --

```
[-14, 101, 124, 86, 33, 112, 288, 330, 195, 16]
```

I think I want something that uses the index and the value to evaluate the preceding value, if values 1 or 255 are found.

I've started with the below, but lost the thread at the end of the day.

```
for i, a in enumerate(data):
    if a == 255:
       neg = i,a
```

If anyone can recommend a better way to handle binary values I'm open to learning about that as well. Help appreciated!

Comment: What does `lost the thread at the end of the day.` mean?

Comment: Ha, it's a euphemism for being tired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can viewcast to `'<i2'`(`<` stands for little endian, `i` for signed integer and `2` for 2 bytes)

```
x = np.array([242, 255, 101, 0, 124, 0, 86, 0, 33, 0, 
       112, 0, 32, 1, 74, 1, 195, 0, 16, 0], dtype=np.uint8)

x.view('<i2')
# array([-14, 101, 124,  86,  33, 112, 288, 330, 195,  16], dtype=int16)
```

Or you can use `'<i2'` directly with `fromfile`.